# The partial header could not be found

Tags: express, hbs

The partial header could not be found how to solve this problem
I don't know how to solve this problem

[image: folder stucher image]

```
const express = require('express');

const port = 3000;

const app = express();

const hbs = require('hbs');

const path = require('path');


const templetpath = path.join(__dirname,"../tempEngin/templet/views");

const partial = path.join(__dirname,"../tempEngin/templet/partial")

app.set('view engine',"hbs");

app.use(express.static("templet"));

 hbs.registerPartials('partial');

app.set('views',templetpath);


app.get("",(req,res)=>{
   res.render("index")
})

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("server created")
})
```